# Using pip in Jupyter caused kernel dead in Google Dataproc cluster

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I created a Dataproc cluster with the following commands:

```sh
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create my-cluster \
    --project my-project \
    --bucket my-bucket \
    --region my-region \
    --zone my-zone \
    --num-workers 5 \
    --service-account my-service-account \
    --initialization-actions gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/connectors/connectors.sh,gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/datalab/datalab.sh,gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/python/conda-install.sh,gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/python/pip-install.sh \
    --metadata gcs-connector-version=2.0.0 \
    --metadata bigquery-connector-version=1.0.0 \
    --scopes cloud-platform \
    --optional-components=ANACONDA,JUPYTER,ZEPPELIN,PRESTO \
    --metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=numpy scipy pandas scikit-learn matplotlib seaborn' \
    --metadata 'CONDA_PACKAGES=tensorflow' \
    --image-version=1.4 \
    --properties '^#^spark:spark.jars=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar#spark:spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.4#zeppelin:zeppelin.notebook.gcs.dir=gs://${BUCKET}/notebooks/zeppelin/${CLUSTER_NAME}#dataproc:jupyter.notebook.gcs.dir=gs://${BUCKET}/notebooks/jupyter/${CLUSTER_NAME}'
```

However, when I use the pip command to update in Jupyter cluster: `pip install --upgrade pip`, it caused the Jupyter kernel dead and restarting continuously, and makes Jupyter unusable. I don't understand why it happened. Any suggestions or clues are appreciated.

Comment: How do you run `pip install --upgrade pip` command?

Comment: I run with `%%bash`, then `pip install --upgrade pip` in one cell.

Comment: You need to run it using init action during cluster startup, because running in the notebook will not execute this command on all nodes of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `pip install --upgrade pip` in the notebook, you need to write an [initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions) that will run this command during cluster startup on all cluster nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would try to install pip at initialization. However, there are still cases that after the cluster is created, some packages get really outdated and need to be updated. I don't want to re-create a new cluster everytime updating packages. How would you suggest handling such scenario? I'm using pip as example, but I was looking for a method to solve such problem.

Comment: I think that this is a limitation of Jupyter and Python, not Dataproc, so hardly anything could be done about this. Anyway, it's strongly recommended to modify your workflow to use ephemeral clusters (clusters that you can create on demand with configuration that you need for your current task) instead of maintaining and re-configuring a single long-running cluster - you will save money, improve reliability and simplify maintenance this way.